# Docker image fails to push to azure registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

Angular application dockerize using Linux container and then pushed to azure registry successfully, however it failed to push to azure registry when dockerize using windows container. Attached picture shows the error `EOF`

could anyone help to explain what `EOF` mean and why the image failed to push ?

[image]

Comment: May I know how the status of this? Did you has any puzzle on below explanation? If yes, free to comment:-)

Answer (score 0):

> What EOF mean

**EOF** is short for `End of file`. Generally, it means [a condition in a computer operating system where no more data can be read from a data source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

With the docker scenario, it is a very common problem and often caused by slow/unstable connections. The nutshell is, it prompt because of **timeout**.

> Why the image failed to push

Here it has couple of reasons can cause this issue and error message.

*1)* The image is very large. Especially the larger the layers, the more fragile it is.

*2)* The network latency issue.

*3)* This error will occur in another situation, which is also ever handled by our team, is attempting to pull a `Linux image` from `windows`, or a `windows image` from `mac`.

I guess here your issue more relevant with the third one, but lack of troubleshooting way to prove that. You can do these by yourself to narrow down the error cause.

Comment: It might be the image size issue but will try to figure it out.